# External drives on USB hub

Tags: usb, usb-storage

I've had problems with (new) 2TB drive that has an endemic problem with that range of hardware (Seagate Expansion drives, if you're interested. There are 33 pages of moaning users on their forums) so given that it's taken me days to copy the files off again, I've decided to get 2 x 1TB drives instead.

If I connect both of these drives to a USB hub will they struggle with bandwidth copying files to each other, or should I connect them direct to the laptop, or one to a hub (with the mouse and keyboard) and the other to a direct connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that connecting them both directly would be the best solution, but you might get away with connecting one to the hub.

Assuming that the limitation on read/write speed on the drives is the USB bandwidth, connecting them both to the hub would limit both of them to the single 480 Mbps limit of USB 2. Since your mouse and keyboard are low-bandwidth devices, their presence on the hub should not significantly affect transfer speeds.