# USB hub that doesn't suck?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes a good and reliable USB Hub?](https://superuser.com/questions/260646/what-makes-a-good-and-reliable-usb-hub)

Hi,

It could be just my bad luck, but it seems like whenever I have used USB hubs they are completely useless.

For example, my new laptop only has 2 usb ports (oops should have checked that before buying), but I have a minimum of 3-4 USB devices I like to use at once.

I bought a ~£5 USB hub (4 ports) and it fails with more than two devices plugged in. Even lately just a keyboard+mouse combo fails.

So, my question is, is this to be expected? Is it my laptop? Or just a cheap hub? i.e. If I go out and buy another one, should I expect a different result? Does anyone have any recommendations for a good hub?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

EDIT: I just found these threads, which makes me think getting a powered hub might solve my woes?
[External drives on USB hub](https://superuser.com/questions/175407/external-drives-on-usb-hub)
[What makes a good and reliable USB Hub?](https://superuser.com/questions/260646/what-makes-a-good-and-reliable-usb-hub)

**UPDATE: I've got a powered USB hub and it was the best decision ever. solved all of my problems.**

Comment: I have 2, 4 port mini hubs connected to my laptop (6 devices), neither are powered, no problems ever. I hope you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a powered hub is what you want.

The USB bus should only supply 100mA per port.  Connecting a port to a non-powered hub would mean that the 100mA supplied by the computer has to be split between all the devices plugged into the hub.

> A USB controller or hub is required to power one unit load (100 mA, a low power load). It can optionally power up to 5 unit loads (500 mA, a high power load)

A non-powered hub is only really any use when all (or most) of the devices plugged into it are self-powered (have their own power supply).

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is about bandwidth, not power. It cannot hurt to try using three low power things (usb flash drives) and seeing if it fails. As a rule though, it can never hurt to have a powered hub.

Comment: thanks mate. would vote your answer up but dont have the rep yet

Comment: No problem, don't worry about it.